# Relation between size and order of a graph k- chromatical critical

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

How can i prove the following statement?
Let $G$ be a graph k-critical of order = $n$ and size = $q$. Show that $k \le  \frac{2q + n}{n}$

Comment: Mind showing us what you've thought about/tried? People here like it a lot more if you do.

Comment: I pretty much lost, i though i could use the fact that $\sum_{i=0}^n \delta(vi) = 2q$ and that $\delta (v) \ge k-1, \forall v \in V(G)$ that in combination with the first graph theorem that says that the sum of the degree of the vertex is equal at two time the edges. But i dont know how terminate the proof, at the time when i need to incorporate the sum,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that, in any $k$-critical graph, the degree of each node is at least $(k-1)$. (Otherwise you could arbitrarily colour all other nodes and then still have choice for the colour of a less-connected node - meaning you could discard it without reducing $k$). This gives you: $$ q \ge \frac 12 . n . (k-1) $$
Take it from there to get your answer.